# I am getting the EXC_BREAKPOINT error. Can any one tell me what is this . Also It is coming from appstore release in crashlytics

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, ios6

```
 Thread 0: com.apple.main-thread
            0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a7b50fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
            1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3a6fe129 pthread_mutex_lock + 392
            2  WebCore                        0x3835a4b1 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 336
            3  WebCore                        0x3835b3b7 WebThreadLock + 66
            4  UIKit                          0x342f23b9 -[UIWebDocumentView _restoreScrollPointForce:] + 72
            5  UIKit                          0x342f2261 -[UIWebDocumentView _resetForNewPage] + 412
            6  UIKit                          0x342be4c9 -[UIWebDocumentView layoutSubviews] + 76
            7  UIKit                          0x34237803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 258
            8  QuartzCore                     0x33fe1d8b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 214
            9  QuartzCore                     0x33fe1929 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 460
            10 QuartzCore                     0x33fe285d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
            11 QuartzCore                     0x33fe2243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
            12 QuartzCore                     0x33fe2051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
            13 QuartzCore                     0x33fe1eb1 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 60
            14 CoreFoundation                 0x324016cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
            15 CoreFoundation                 0x323ff9c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
            16 CoreFoundation                 0x323ffd17 __CFRunLoopRun + 742
            17 CoreFoundation                 0x32372ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
            18 CoreFoundation                 0x32372d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
            19 GraphicsServices               0x35f252eb GSEventRunModal + 74
            20 UIKit                          0x34288301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
```

I am getting EXC_BREAKPOINT. I am not getting why this is coming in the appstore release. When this error comes. As I am getting this in most of the cases.

```
    Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: my tough was its come form multithread problem arise in your projects

Comment: describes more details on error. how it comes and what kind of operation trying to get this error